# Области видимости, момент вызова деструкторов (С++)

Tags: c++, неопределённое-поведение

Есть ли UB в следующем коде?

```
thread *func_thread = new thread[thrn]; // стандартная <thread>, но не суть

// ...

for(auto i = 0; i < thrn; i += 1) {
    func_thread[i] = thread(thf);
} // Будут ли тут вызваны деструкторы7

// ...

for(auto i = 0; i < thrn; i += 1) {
    auto &x = func_thread[i]; // Если деструкторы вызваны, то здесь UB?
    if(x.joinable()) {
        x.join();
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вы имеете в виду деструктор `thread`?

В коде проблем не видно: в этой точке используется [перемещающий оператор присваивания](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/operator%3D), и временный объект `thread` после него более не ссылается на живой thread, и спокойно умирает.

Comment: Тогда здесь ideone.com/i3CpX8 бред из-за того, что я не реализовал перемещающее присваивание? И ещё, чтобы не плодить лишние сущности, иногда больше подходит malloc? @VladD

Comment: @Nex: Ну, почему бред, вроде всё нормально?

Comment: Я пытаюсь понять, сколько объектов реально создает такой код (включая временные). В строках 22-23 (и 36-37) - вызываются деструкторы временных объектов (которые в правой части присваивания). Тогда в строке 42 вызываются методы объектов, создание которых там не видно? @VladD

Comment: @Nex: Ну, хм. Ничего необычного не вижу. Строка 20 — 2 конструктора. Строка 22 — конструктор временного объекта, оператор = (который у вас не определён, используется дефолтный), деструктор временного объекта; всё выполняется 2 раза. Строка 31 — два деструктора.

Comment: @Nex: Строка 34 — просто выделение памяти, никаких конструкторов. Строка 36 — дважды вызов `operator=` на несконструированном объекте, это UB. Ну и конструктор/деструктор временного объекта. Строка 44 — просто освобождение памяти.

Comment: @Nex: Вы не должны экономить сущности. Пустой объект ничего не стоит. Экономить лучше копирование, а вот перемещение обычно практически бесплатно.

Comment: @Nex, какие-то сомнения с C++? [Почитайте подборку](http://harmful.cat-v.org/software/c++/), ну, и сбоку там, высказывания RMS и Линуса на эту тему.

Comment: @avp я уже понял, что Вам не хватает особого знака: "противник С++". Но сколько ПО на нем уже понаписали.

Comment: @Nex, ну, да. Поэтому знать-то его нужно, а вот писать на нем... ?